# android calling runnable object multiple times

Tags: android, media-player, runnable

I'm trying to call my function multiple times, which contains runnable object. 
Can anybody tell me What I'm doing wrong ?

```
        handler = new Handler();

        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                rounds = new Integer(et.getText().toString());
            //  handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                for (int j = 0; j <= rounds; j ++)
                {
                    f();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void f()
    {
        r = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Box.this, R.drawable.sound1);
                 mp.setLooping(false);
                 mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                 mp.start();
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 4000);
        mp.stop();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error loading keycharmap file.

Comment: you are doing so many things wrong :S ... you are creating a never ending handler loop.. and in each loop you are creating and starting the mediaplayer

Answer (score 1):

check out this-

```
 Handler handler;
    sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    rounds = new Integer(et.getText().toString());
                    for (int j = 0; j <= rounds; j ++)
                    {
                        f();
                    }
                }
            });

    public void f()
    {
          r = new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                   handler = new Handler() {
                   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(Box.this, R.drawable.sound1);
                   mp.setLooping(false);
                   mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                   mp.start(); 
                   handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,3000);//3 sec
                   msg.what = 2;//removing first executed handler this is u missing.
                    };
                 };
                handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1,4000);//4sec
                }
           }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same error: 
Can't open keycharmap file
Error loading keycharmap file.

Comment: why u calling this thr for loop as its execute multiple time it will start handler with same id so it will give error if u call once without for loop it will executed well may be u r having problem in logic